# How to pass the value in the param with array type

Tags: c#, web-services

I am very new to C# I have added one service reference. So what I have to do it here pass three value in one method, 2 parameter are strings and I know its values. But the third Parameter is written as :

```
public FM2CRM.CRMTicketService.TicketCRMCreateOrUpdateRequest[] TicketCRMRequest {
        get {
            return this.TicketCRMRequestField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.TicketCRMRequestField, value) != true)) {
                this.TicketCRMRequestField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("TicketCRMRequest");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I am not able to understand what kind of data it accepts. And how to pass the value in this parameter.

In ticketCRMCreateorUpdateRequest Class :

```
public partial class TicketCRMCreateOrUpdateRequest : FM2CRM.CRMTicketService.TicketBase {

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private FM2CRM.CRMTicketService.FileRequest[] AllegatiField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public FM2CRM.CRMTicketService.FileRequest[] Allegati {
        get {
            return this.AllegatiField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.AllegatiField, value) != true)) {
                this.AllegatiField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Allegati");
            }
        }
    }
```

Can any body please help how to pass the value in `TicketCRMRequest` ? Thanks in Advance.

UPDATE:

This is my complete Class :

```
 public void UpdateCRMTickets() {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        CRMTicketServiceClient ticketClient = new CRMTicketServiceClient();

        GetTicketCRMRequest CRMticketRequest = new GetTicketCRMRequest();
        CRMticketRequest.Sorgente = "FM";
        CRMticketRequest.TicketIDCRM = "CRM000000340                                      ";
        GetTicketCRMResponse ticketResponse = ticketClient.GetTicketCRM(CRMticketRequest);

        TicketCRMCreateOrUpdateRequest ticketCRMRequest = new TicketCRMCreateOrUpdateRequest();
        CreateOrUpdateTicketCRMRequest updateticketRequests = new CreateOrUpdateTicketCRMRequest();


        ticketCRMRequest.Allegati = FM2CRM.CRMTicketService.File[0];

        updateticketRequests.Sorgente = "FM";
        updateticketRequests.TicketCRMRequest = TicketCRMCreateOrUpdateRequest(ticketResponse);
        updateticketRequests.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
        CreateOrUpdateTicketCRMResponse updateticketResponse = ticketClient.CreateOrUpdateTicketCRM(updateticketRequests);

    }
```

Comment: The type `FM2CRM.CRMTicketService.TicketCRMCreateOrUpdateRequest[]` is an array of that custom class.  Whatever `TicketCRMCreateOrUpdateRequest` is, make an array of those.  Aside from that it's not really clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: @David I have updated my question, thats my complete Class function

Comment: And what specifically isn't working in this `UpdateCRMTickets` method?  Are you getting an error message?  An unexpected result?  When you step through in a debugger, what is the first thing that goes wrong?